# Setting occurrence number in Sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, find-occurrences

Can anyone check my sql query, when using a select statement, the occurrence_number column shows correct values.

```
select t.[Employee Number], t.Document_Type, t.Document_Name,
 row_number() over (partition by document_type
                          order by right(document_name, 6)
                         ) as occurrence_number
from BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM t
```

**Working**
[image: working screenshot]

when I using update statement, the occurrence number messed up.

```
update BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM
set Occurrence = R.occurrence_number
from (select t.[Employee Number], t.Document_Type, t.Document_Name,
 row_number() over (partition by document_type
                          order by right(document_name, 6)
                         ) as occurrence_number
from BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM t) R
where BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM.Document_Name = r.Document_Name
```

**Not working**
 [image: not working]

Comment: both images are same

Comment: i just updated the screenshot.

Comment: same try with replace update statement to select statement "select BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM.*, r.Occurrence from (select t.[Employee Number], t.Document_Type, t.Document_Name,
 row_number() over (partition by document_type
                          order by right(document_name, 6)
                         ) as occurrence_number
from BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM t) R
where BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM.Document_Name = r.Document_Name "

Comment: You need something unique to join on. Record 6 and 7 are identical, so you won't know wich  rownumber it will get. I'm not a big fan of cursors, but in this case you need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a duplicate row with the same `document_name` so that `where` clause is not working how you might expect.

You can get around this using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and updating that cte directly like so:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      t.[Employee Number]
    , t.Document_Type
    , t.Document_Name
    , t.occurrence
    , occurrence_number = row_number() over (
        partition by document_type 
        order by right(document_name, 6)
      )
   from BluePrismProcesses.dbo.PID0147_DM t
)

update cte
  set occurrence =  occurrence_number
where (occurrence <> occurrence_number or occurrence is null);
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZVO11388

returns:

```
+-----------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
| Employee Number | Doc_Count | Document_Type | Document_Name | Occurrence |
+-----------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
|          406453 |         2 | offer         |        092735 |          1 |
|          406453 |         2 | offer         |        092735 |          2 |
|          406453 |         2 | offer         |        092848 |          3 |
|          406453 |         2 | offer         |        092848 |          4 |
|          406453 |         2 | offer         |        092848 |          5 |
+-----------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: I tried using the query you made, no changes has been made.

Comment: @yope is `occurrence` currently `null` ?

Comment: @yope see the update `where (occurrence <> occurrence_number or occurrence is null);`